# Probability of taking two or more white balls from an urn

Tags: probability

With $n$ balls ($w$ white and $n-w$ black) what is the probability that you pick 2 or more white balls given that you draw $\ell$ times without returning?

I am not actually looking for the exact expression but more an upper bound on the probability.  Someone told me that an answer is, but without explanation:

$Pr \leq \binom{w}{2} (\frac{\ell}{n})^2$

If someone could help get this upper bound or another similar I would be grateful.

Comment: Why do you think you can merely *bound* the probability, not calculate it exactly?

Comment: It is because I need it to make other more complex calculations with this, and the simpler the equation I get, the simpler the further calculations will get.

Comment: Your comment makes no sense.  Equations are always simpler when they can be solved exactly than when you get a mere bound.  Proof:  OK, here's a bound:  the probability is less than $1.0$.  (Does that simple answer help you?  Of course not.)

Comment: This probability is for a runtime of an algorithm, this is the first step of the algorithm and I need to multiply several other probabilities and then calculate the expected number of times you need to execute an iteration to make an event happen certain amount of times. The point is that I do not need an exact probability and working with exact probabilities is tedious and unnecessary for me. It is better to work with bounds. I have already tried to do it exact and after some steps the equation is really long and in the end I will bound everything since I am calculating runtimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as asking what the probability is that the last $n-\ell$ draws contain either $w$ or $w-1$ white balls. The number of ways of this happening is
$$\binom{n-\ell}{w} + \binom{\ell}{1}\binom{n-\ell}{w-1}.$$